# hide image broken link while not downloaded to browser(mozilla firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i am showing a image which was over AWS, but it takes time, till then a broken image link is displaying, i want to hide this broken link untill the image loaded.

---

**html**

```
<img id='myprofilepic' src='http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/pub/image-a81XkVF4ZnB2u0lwSdEJVHYKf4sS4NrSY8LMoJz4fPJspmdGa81MeyE4fOycprOehvQ6/govind-singh-nagarkoti.jpg'>
//image is at aws s3 which was taking too much time above is just an example
```

---

**css**

```
#myprofilepic{
width:75px;
height:75px;
padding:1px;
border:1px solid #021a40;
background-color:#ff0;
}
```

Comment: your image tag should be self closed and an alt tag would be good for valid HTML `<img id="" src="" alt="" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to set the img src as a 1 pixel transparent GIF, and set the real image as a background:

HTML:

```
<img id="myprofilepic" src="transparent.gif" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
#myprofilepic{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #021a40;
    background-color: #ff0;
    background-image: url('http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/pub/image-a81XkVF4ZnB2u0lwSdEJVHYKf4sS4NrSY8LMoJz4fPJspmdGa81MeyE4fOycprOehvQ6/govind-singh-nagarkoti.jpg');
}
```

The idea behind this is that the 1x1 GIF will load quickly and background images do not display broken image links.